# ssh is not aware of client hostname?

Tags: ssh

I have two servers. Say A and B.

I `ssh-copy-id`ed on both servers to each other.

And I can connect from A to B without password. But I failed to connect from B to A.

I found that audit log is different

```
B's log when connecting from A to B (success)
    ... (hostname=192.168.0.1, addr=192.168.0.1, terminal=sshd ref=success

A's log when connecting from B to A (failed)
    ... (hostname=?, addr=192.168.0.1, terminal=sshd ref=failed
```

Where should I look into?

Here comes what `ssh -v` showed.

```
$ ssh -v user@<a's ip address>
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to <a_ip_address> [a_ip_address] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: loaded 3 keys
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '<a_ip_address>' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/<user>/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<user>/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/<user>/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@<a_ip_address>'s password:
```

Comment: From B, run `ssh -v A`.  The option `-v` means verbose.  Copy that result to the text of your question so that we can see where it is failing.

Comment: From B, try: `ssh -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no A`.  This suggestion comes from [here](http://injustfiveminutes.com/category/ssh/).  If that doesn't work, have a look at some of the suggestions [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/464411/trying-to-ssh-in-to-remote-computer-but-still-asking-for-password).

Comment: @John1024 No difference. Just asking gosh-darned password. Do you want me to with `-v`?

Comment: Some people who had similar error messages noted a bug with `ssh-copy-id` and permissions.  See: http://serverfault.com/questions/464411/trying-to-ssh-in-to-remote-computer-but-still-asking-for-password

Comment: Remove the edit and add it as an answer.  That way, other users will be able to find it and upvote it.

Comment: @garethTheRed Thanks for the advice. I put my own answer. Id there any way to select previous edit? Or should I just re-edit?

Comment: @JinKwon I just did that for you.  And, yes, there is a simple way to select a previous edit: it is the `rollback` button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of my problem is that the home directory, the `.ssh` directory, and its child files on the target server have a wrong permissions.

I discovered this issue by looking at messages in log files in `/var/log` such as `secure`, and `audit/*`.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the questions asked, even though they turned out to not be the OP's actual problem, in case searchers are looking for that actual question:

- sshd tries to determine the client's hostname if configuration option `UseDNS` is on. The upstream default for this was 'yes' until 6.8 in 2015-03 (just after the Q was posted), but distros or packages may change the default, and of course a sysadmin can always override the default. But the availability and/or correctness of the client hostname has no effect on public-key authentication, only some info in the log entries.
- `ssh-copy-id` is so named because it copies a publickey file which implicitly identifies a *user* -- not a host -- and these files by default are named like `id_rsa.pub id_dsa.pub id_ecdsa.pub id_ed25519.pub` although this can be changed. A publickey file *may* (or may not) contain a comment that gives the user name, and by default `ssh-keygen` creates this comment as `userid@hostname` where the key is *generated* (which may differ from where the key is used for a connection), but this can be overridden or changed or removed.